# Referenced Memory in runtrace for OllyDBG 1.x

Tags: ollydbg

I wanted to know if there is any way I could get the referenced memory in the run trace?
I tried using OllyDBG 2.x but it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Please provide some more details, for example, which commands you perform to get the run trace and what output you get. As far as I know, `Trace`->`Run hit trace` and then `View`->`Run trace` should show you the memory referenced.

Comment: I use the same steps to see the trace...Trace->Run hit trace and then View->Run trace. However it only shows the modified registers and not the referenced memory. I also checked if there were any options to toggle memory references for the trace but didnt find any.